# Is the direct sum of simple Lie algebras semisimple?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

All Lie algebras in this post are assumed to be finite-dimensional.

A Lie algebra $L$ is called semisimple if its radical $\operatorname{Rad}(L)$, i.e. the unique maximal solvable ideal of $L$, is $0$.

Suppose that $L$ is a Lie algebra and there exist simple ideals $I_1, \dots, I_n\lhd L$ such that
$$L = I_1 \oplus \dots \oplus I_n$$ (vector space direct sum = Lie algebra direct sum). Is it true that $L$ is semisimple?

I tried to argue as follows: as a Lie algebra, each $I_t$ is simple and thus semisimple. It thus suffices to show (by induction) that
$$\operatorname{Rad}(L_1\oplus L_2) = \operatorname{Rad}(L_1)\oplus \operatorname{Rad}(L_2)$$
for any Lie algebras $L_1, L_2$. However, I am not able to show this. Is this equality even true?

A duplicate was proposed, which is not relevant...

Comment: $Rad(L_{1}⊕L_{2})=Rad(L_{1})⊕Rad(L_{2})$,the RHS is included in the $LHS$,this follows from the fact that the commutator of the direct sum is the direct sum of the commutators and the fact that the radical contains every solvable ideal, in particular the direct sum of solvable ideals is a solvable ideals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment, we can suppose that $L_{1},L_{2}$ (replace $L_{i}$ by $L_{i}/Rad(L_{i})$) are semi-simple. Let $J$ be a solvable ideal of $L_{1}⊕L_{2}$. Then necessarily $J\cap L_{i}={0}$, so the projections $P_{i}:L_{1}⊕L_{2}\mapsto L_{i}$ are injective when restricted $J$. But at the same time $P_{i}(J)$ are homomorphic images of a solvable ideal, hence solvable, so $P_{i}(J)={0}$. This shows that the direct sum of semi-simple lie algebras is semi-simple, and in particular that  $Rad(L_{1}⊕L_{2})=Rad(L_{1})⊕Rad(L_{2})$.